# Command Line Text Editor

Tags: c#, command-line, text-editor

Basically I want to make a command line text editor in C#. I've had a look at some tutorials but most of them seem to be using a GUI, I want just pure command line like nano. I was wondering if there were any good tutorials or things I could look into?

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain you can accomplish most of what you're trying to do just by using the [System.Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) class.

You could use the ConsoleKeyInfo class and Console.ReadKey() to detect arrow key presses as follows:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo pressed_key = Console.ReadKey(); // read keystroke

if (pressed_key.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
{
     Console.CursorTop = Console.CursorTop - 1;
}
```